# Problem detecting temperature and speed sensors in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, sensors, lm-sensors, psensor

I installed lm-sensors and then psensor to monitor temperature and speed on my Ubuntu laptop, but when I run `sudo sensors-detect`, I get "`No i2c device files found`". Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Add the output of the following commands, please: `lspci`, `lsb-release -cd` and also check `dmesg` regarding any errors about modules or devices.